# Password recovery helper doesn't open my modal with meteor

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm using this guide to implement a password reset. When the user clicks the generated link it should open my "resetPassword" modal in Bootstrap.

http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor

In my client\main.js I have this code:

```
Template.recoverpopup.helpers({
    resetPassword : function(t) {
        return Session.get('resetPassword');
        Modal.show('reset_password');
    }
});

if (Accounts._resetPasswordToken) {
    Session.set('resetPassword', Accounts._resetPasswordToken);
}
```

The resetPassword session variable returns a value through the console. I'm new to Meteor and I'm still figuring it all out but I think the function isn't running.

Template code:

```
<template name="recoverpopup">
    {{#if resetPassword}}
        <div class="modal fade" id="reset_password" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="loginmodal-container">
                    <h1>Reset je wachtwoord</h1><br>
                    <div id="reset_error" class="alert alert-danger hide">
                        <strong>Error:</strong>
                    </div>

                    <form id="resetform">
                        <input type="password" name="pass" id="newpassword" placeholder="Nieuw wachtwoord">
                        <input type="submit" name="reset" class="register loginmodal-submit" value="Reset">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{else}}
        <div class="modal fade" id="recovermodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="loginmodal-container">
                    <h1>Wachtwoord vergeten</h1><br>
                    <div id="recover_error" class="alert alert-danger hide">
                        <strong>Error:</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div id="recover_info" class="alert alert-info hide">
                        <strong>Info:</strong>
                    </div>
                    <form id="recoverform">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email-adres">
                        <!--<input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">-->
                        <input type="submit" name="recover" class="login loginmodal-submit" value="Verstuur">
                    </form>

                    <div class="login-help">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registermodal" onclick="$('#recovermodal').modal('hide');">Registreer</a> - <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginmodal" onclick="$('#recovermodal').modal('hide');" >Login</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your guide but according to what I see in your code I'd suggest to leave it. You have perfect one at offical [docs.meteor.com](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app).

To help you: if you want to call some action do not observe your Session element with helper. Helpers are like getters - for receiving data.
What you want to use is client-side event.

I will not give you straight sollution but simple and readable example how you should behave with Meteor. Let's assume you press button with id="resetPass" and you have declared modal with id="resetPassModal".

What you do is watching an event:

```
Template.yourTemplateName.events({
    "click #resetPass": function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#resetPassModal").show()
    }
});
```

Keep in mind that "[Multiple open modals not supported](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)"
For more details ask in comments or create .